# Install-Package : Unable to find package 'CommonServiceLocator.MefAdapter

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I like to include `CommonServiceLocator.MefAdapter` in my Visual Studio Community 2015 project.
When I try to install the package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator.MefAdapter/1.0.0

I get the error:

> PM>  Install-Package CommonServiceLocator.MefAdapter 
>       Install-Package : Unable to find package    'CommonServiceLocator.MefAdapter'
>       At line:1 char:17
>       +  Install-Package <<<<  CommonServiceLocator.MefAdapter 
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Answer (score 11):

Check out that your path to NuGet server is correct.

You can do it in this way: Tools->Options->NuGet Package Manager(use search). Check that your path is https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

[image]

I had created a project and I could install this package there.

Answer (score 4):

If you have more than one source registered for Nuget, in Visual Studio 2015 you may need to select the correct source from the dropdown in the top left corner of the Package Manager Console.

[image: Drop down]

Answer (score 0):

check your NuGet package manager
if this is happening probably it is empty
hence add this

https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
in source
and name it
nuget.org

hit update and check if it works.